# Unable to get div attributes

Tags: html

I am trying to get the attributes for a selected div, when i do alert and the div name, it give me the div name but when i do alert divname.style.backgroundcolor, it gives me an error, undefined. I have noticed that its only when i add the attribute to the selected div, it gives me an error and if i type the name of the div directly with the attribute
it gives me the right answer.

```
     function getdiv(){
     var selecteddivname = document.getElementById("divname").value;
     alert(selecteddivname); // this works, it shows the divname right
     alert(selecteddivname.id); // its shows undefined
     alert(selecteddivname.style.backgroundColor); //its shows undefined
     alert(moused.style.backgroundColor); //this works, mouse being the actual div name
 }
```

Comment: Your `selecteddivname` is a string because you have `document.getElementById("divname").value`. If you want the element then don't use the `.value` so `document.getElementById("divname")` see http://jsfiddle.net/5hakc93s/

Comment: Can we see your HTML? `<div>` elements don't have a `value` property. And if they did, that value property would not have its own id or style.

Comment: @Huangism, selecteddivname value is moused

Comment: @Sebastian not sure what you mean, moused is not defined in your code. You get undefined because you are trying to get the `.id` of a string

Comment: @Huangism , i have put the whole code in there , please check

Comment: @Sebastian check for what? I already told you why it is not working. Look at Paul's answer, it explains the same thing. The `.id` and `.style` can be called on the html element but you are calling it on a string so it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get at the attributes of a `div` *identified* by the `input` with the id `divname`.

If so:

```
function getdiv(){
  var selecteddivname = document.getElementById("divname").value;
  var selecteddiv = document.getElementById(selecteddivname);

  console.log(selecteddivname); 
  console.log(selecteddiv.id);    // should match
  console.log(selecteddiv.style.backgroundColor); 
  console.log(moused.style.backgroundColor); 
}
```

Comment: console log < -- am not familiar with, i am checking on the net right now about it , is it similar to alert ?

Comment: Yes. Writes to the  [Javascript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) instead of making you click on all those popup windows. You'll want to get familiar with the console, anyway.

Comment: that did it @Paul Roub, i put alert instead of console.log , i am gonna research and learn concole stuff as well .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try to use valid attributes for div like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdiv(){
var selecteddivname = document.getElementById("divname").id;
alert(selecteddivname); // this works, it shows the divname right
alert(selecteddivname.id); // its shows undefined
alert(selecteddivname.style.backgroundColor); //its shows undefined
alert(moused.style.backgroundColor); //this works
 }
</script>
```

and here the tag

```
<div id="divname" name="mahmoud"   onmouseover="getdiv()" >how are you      guys</div>
```

hope this be helpful